# JAX-WS and version conflicts

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

As test project I've create a very simple WebService using wsdl and jax-ws. The client runs very well if it is deployed as web application in GlassFish but if I start the same (WebService-)Code in Eclipse directly, I get the following error:

```
WARNUNG: Input Action on WSDL operation AddNumbers and @Action on its associated Web Method addNumbers did not match and will cause problems in dispatching the requests
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.mc.runtime.McConfigurationFactory.createInstance(McConfigurationFactory.java:66)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.mc.runtime.McTubeFactory.createTube(McTubeFactory.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:608)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:312)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
    at mnm.namedesdienstes.webservice.service.NameDesDienstesService.getNameDesDienstesPortTypePort(NameDesDienstesService.java:56)
    at webserviceClient.NameDesDienstesClient.myTest(NameDesDienstesClient.java:12)
    at webserviceClient.NameDesDienstesClient.main(NameDesDienstesClient.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.ha.store.api.BackingStoreException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 16 more
```

After some research I found out that it must have something to do with different versions of some library files. So now my question is, how can I "fix" my eclipse java execution to run my webservice client correctly? I've found some tips to copy some jar to an endorsed-directory, but which jars into which directory :-)

I'm using Max OS 10.6.8, Eclipse Project uses JVM 1.6. My Mac Java Version is

```
xmacbook:~ cstraube$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)
```

**UPDATE**: My first try (thanks to the link from remipod) I performed the following steps:

1. Get the directory of endorsed lirbaries with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));`
2. Next, I copied the two files JAXWS2.1.7-20090419.jar and JAXB2_20080513.jar (both Version 2.1.7) into this directory
3. Unfortunately I get still the same error

Comment: Create your own BackupStoreException from this file:
http://svn-mirror.glassfish.org/glassfish-svn/trunk/api/ha-api/src/main/java/org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException.java Worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy the [fitting](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#mustanga1) versions of jaxws-api.jar and jaxb-api.jar into the directory /Library/Java/Home/lib/endorsed (Mac).

Comment: You might need to add the ha-api.jar (keeping in mind the version) as this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 11):

I have similar problem with yours  when deploying web service (JAX-WS) in tomcat 7. 
The missing class definition could be found in ha-api.jar.



`org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException`

You should add the ha-api.jar (From JAX-WS distribution) into server lib. For my case, the eclipse run tomcat 7, so the location is (Tomcat 7.0\lib).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link [JAX WS with WS 2.1.1](http://metro.java.net/guide/Using_JAX_WS_2_1_with_JavaSE6.html). You will need to give precedence to your version of jaxws to the provided jaxws from the jre 1.6.

**Edit:**
Glassfish already includes some libraries, as well as java 6. I had to track down version conflicts with jaxws in glassfish 3.1 / 3.1.1 and java 6 / 7. You might check the exact java runtime eclipse uses to start the application and look for duplicate jars on the effective classpath.

The endorsed mechanism just provides an easy and error prone way to override the included jaxws distribution. Error prone, because your colleague will suffer from the same problem.

I havn't seen the exception org.glassfish.ha.store.api.BackingStoreException in the context of jaxws. Your version conflict could be created by another library than jaxws...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same exception

> org.glassfish.ha.store.api.BackingStoreException

And after ensuring my JAX-WS and JAX-B jars were all the same version the issue was still occurring.

**THE FIX**: I then added the `ha-api.jar` to the WEB-INF\lib directory and this solved the issue.

The clue here was the "ha" package in the exceptions class path as seen above. Hope this helps!