# GlassFish Metro outbound webservice call with client certificate fails

Tags: ssl, glassfish, java-metro-framework, client-certificates

I'm trying to connect to a partner web service using GlassFish 3.1.2.2 w/ Metro JAX-WS and I'm getting HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: SSL client certificate is required.

I've imported the private key our partner provided into GlassFish's keystore:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore XXX.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks
$ keytool -changealias -alias "le-75e085d7-0ceb-4734-ac52-0e64646924c8" -destalias "XXX" -keystore keystore.jks
$ keytool -keypasswd -alias XXX -keystore keystore.jks
```

I then set the httpsOutboundKeyAlias property in GlassFish's domain.xml to this new key:

```
$ grep sas domains/dev/config/domain.xml
        <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=XXX</jvm-options>
```

Then, when I make a WS call:

```
[#|2013-03-26T17:58:30.888-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=137;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|#.: ---[HTTP request - https://XXX]---
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://XXX"
User-Agent: Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body>[...]</S:Body></S:Envelope>--------------------
|#]

[#|2013-03-26T17:58:31.847-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=137;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|#.: ---[HTTP response - https://XXX - 403]---
null: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 1913
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 00:58:31 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
[...]
<h2>HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: SSL client certificate is required.<br>Internet Information Services (IIS)</h2>
```

I have this configuration working for other webservices but not this one for some reason... not sure if IIS behaves differently?

I seem to be able to connect fine using curl presenting a pem client cert converted from the partner's pfx file using openssl:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in XXX.pfx -out XXX.pem -nodes
$ curl -vk -E XXX.pem -H "Accept: text/xml, multipart/related" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction: \"http://XXX\"" -d @req.xml  https://XXX
```

so not sure why GlassFish/Metro is not presenting the client certificate in the expected fashion.

Any idea/suggestion on what I may be missing or how to troubleshoot?

I tried to set -Djavax.net.debug=ssl, but bytes are showing up as separate log entries in GlassFish logs so it's pretty unreadable.
I also tried to run it from a standalone Java program outside of the container, but then I run into [classpath issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580803/jax-ws-and-version-conflicts).

Thank you

Comment: When tracing javax.net.debug=ssl I can clearly see the *** CertificateRequest, but Glassfish is not providing any cert after *** Certificate chain, as it is with other instances connecting to other servers.

Comment: I also verified the top CA in the chain of the client cert matches one of the Cert Authorities (1) provided by the server during the handshake and (2) in GlassFish cacerts.jks truststore, so I've no idea why GlassFish is not presenting the client cert...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for posterity in case it helps someone else in the future:
we narrowed it down to a bug  in GlassFish.

We got the connection working using javax.net.ssl libraries, so for whatever reason GlassFish refuses to provide the configured httpsOutboundKeyAlias to that particular server. Not clear of the specific reason as it works for others, but from the ssl logs, it looks like it may be because that IIS server provides a long list of Accepted CAs for the client cert? It's possible the list is longer than expected or GlassFish has problems matching the client cert CA to the list provided? GlassFish devs are welcome to follow up with me directly if they care to fix this bug.

Anyhow, in the meantime, here's the code to make it work:

First, create a custom SSL socket factory using the provided client cert key store:

```
  KeyStore ebKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
  try (InputStream clientCertKeyInput = new FileInputStream(pfxFilePath)) {
      ebKeyStore.load(clientCertKeyInput, passwdChars);
  }
  KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
  keyManagerFactory.init(ebKeyStore, passwdChars);

  SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  sslCtx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), 
              null, // default javax.net.ssl.trustStore
              new SecureRandom());

  sslSocketFactory = sslCtx.getSocketFactory();
```

Then make the SOAP stack use this sslSocketFactory through a property in the port's RequestContext:

```
    Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
    ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
```

The silver lining is that this method of GlassFish to provide client certificate doesn't scale if you need to connect to multiple outbound parties, so now at least this solution resolves this problem as well. :)