# Deploying JAX-WS webservice as War in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, apache, jaxb, jax-ws

I have developed a webservice using JAXWS and able to run it from the eclipse on Tomcat 7 without any problem.

But my question is how to deploy it in Apache a war file. When ever I give Run On Server it ends up with exception **SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException**

And If I log into Apache and try to run from there, I can see this **FAIL - Application at context path /IPWSv2 could not be started**

This is my sun-jaxws.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="IPWSServiceV1" implementation="com.ipws.insurpay.ipwsv1.IPWSServiceV1"
    url-pattern="/IPWSServiceV1" />
</endpoints>
```

And I have this mapping in my web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IPWSServiceV1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/IPWSServiceV1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It works if I run it with the enpoint publisher,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Endpoint.publish("http://host/Project-Name/IPWSServiceV1",
             new IPWSServiceV1());

}
```

Following is the stack trace:

```
   Jun 4, 2013 11:18:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
 SEVERE: Context [/IPWSv2] startup failed due to previous errors
 Jun 4, 2013 11:18:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software       Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\docs
 Jun 4, 2013 11:18:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software   Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\manager
 Jun 4, 2013 11:18:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software   Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT
Jun 4, 2013 11:18:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 4, 2013 11:18:08 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 4, 2013 11:18:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 7668 ms
 Jun 4, 2013 11:22:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer    'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
 Jun 4, 2013 11:22:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
 Jun 4, 2013 11:22:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
 Jun 4, 2013 11:22:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/IPWSv2'
 Jun 4, 2013 11:22:57 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener    parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.<init>  (ServletAdapter.java:95)
at     com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapterList.createHttpAdapter(ServletAdapterList.java:77)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapterList.createHttpAdapter(ServletAdapterList.java:53)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapterList.createAdapter(HttpAdapterList.java:77)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapterList.createAdapter(HttpAdapterList.java:71)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:266)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:152)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    org.glassfish.ha.store.api.BackingStoreException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 38 more
Jun 4, 2013 11:22:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
  SEVERE: Context [/IPWSv2] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 4, 2013 11:22:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

I googled for this but not able to find how to deploy this.

Can any body please suggest me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "_org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException_": Do you have the glassfish classes? Was this your intention?

Comment: I have not manually added them any where and they are not needed to my project also. From where they are coming?

Comment: My build path has just default libraries, EAR, JRE System Libs and Web App Libs. Nothing extra

Comment: I think this question will be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580803/jax-ws-and-version-conflicts. You need to make sure that you have JAX-WS on the classpath

Comment: Thank you, one suggestion in that solved half of my problem i.e. adding ha-api.jar. But still I am getting 404. But now the application is running on server

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I am not doing it with Axis, so there is no html or jsp files to load. But if I access my wsdl url, it is working

Comment: So did that solve it?

Comment: Hey, I removed <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> from web.xml. But still it is throwing 404 when I run. But yes, it is working meaning I am able to access the wsdl url. Will check in SOAP UI and confirm you. Then I will accept your answer

Comment: But can you tell me why is 404?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by copying the file `ha-api.jar` of JAX-WS dependencies and pasting it in `$CATALINA_HOME\lib`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go http://jax-ws.java.net/.
2. Download JAX-WS RI distribution.
3. Unzip it and copy following JAX-WS dependencies to Tomcat library folder “{$TOMCAT}/lib“:

   jaxb-impl.jar,
   jaxws-api.jar,
   jaxws-rt.jar,
   gmbal-api-only.jar,
   management-api.jar,
   stax-ex.jar,
   streambuffer.jar,
   policy.jar.

Cheers!